# Want to modify fragment (How to set image from URL to an imageView)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, imageview

I want to modify my code so my fragment appear an imageView which is an image from URL.
So this is my code:

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
    return view;

}
}
```

I want my layout appear image from an URL so, here is my layout XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iklanpertama"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff3e0"
    android:layout_weight="1.2"
    android:textColor="#212326"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my adapter:

```
public class ma_pager_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            tab1 t1 = new tab1();
            return t1;
        case 1:
            tab2 t2 = new tab2();
            return t2;
        case 2:
            tab3 t3 = new tab3();
            return t3;

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}//set the number of tabs

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Iklan1";
        case 1:

            return "Iklan2";
        case 2:

            return "Iklan3";
    }
    return null;
}



}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can use [this](https://github.com/koush/ion) lib for that

Comment: How to extends that lib with this fragment?

Comment: use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you app gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

Use this in your fragment to show image:

// This is the "long" way to do build an ImageView request... it allows you to set headers, etc.

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/image.png")
.withBitmap()
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.intoImageView(imageView);
```

// but for brevity, use the ImageView specific builder...

```
Ion.with(imageView)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.load("http://example.com/image.png");
```

Comment: whan i try to import your recommended library, android give me a message ion cannot be imported. How to import your library in the right way?

Comment: u had internet connectvity when importing gradle ...i mean good connectivity

Comment: sorry i dont understand what u say

Comment: sometimes it give error when import try again and make sure you had internet connectivity in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this library
 http://square.github.io/picasso/
However remember to look up that ImageView from your inflated view using its id, do that in the same method (
onCreateView).
Then set the image using the library here or the one given before.